# Unable to view receive SMS within fragment

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Hi I wonder if anyone could advise. I have an arduino which is sending GPS coordinates via SMS to my phone. I then need to extract the coordinates and display them as a marker on a map. The map is being implemented as a fragment. Here is my code for the broadcastreceiver class:

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){} }
```

And within the fragment:

```
public BroadcastReceiver receiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver(){
    public static final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //---get the SMS message passed in---
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            String number = "";
            String message = "";
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

                message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();


            }
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};
```

I have also registered the receiver:

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    receiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver,  filter);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    receiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(receiver,  filter);
}
```

I am not getting the toast message displayed onscreen to indicate that the function has run, what have I not understood? I am very new to java and android programming so my understanding is not complete. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you declared your Broadcast receiver in your Manifest?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing action in `IntentFilter` which should be `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED`.

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
receiver = new SmsBroadcastReceiver();
getActivity().registerReceiver(receiver,  filter);
```

Also watch out for Runtime Permission above api 23.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ADM. Unfortunately I'm still not receiving any messages with this change. What else could I try?

Comment: I just tried using a log command to test whether the onReceive function ever runs, and it doesn't

Comment: On which API version you are testing ? Do you have all the above permission in manifest ? and at runtime ?